# Very large data makes my application very slow while using ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, android-nestedscrollview

I am writing an android application which the whole page is scrollable.
So I've tried to use NestedScrollView but the views of recycle view are created too slow since the data is very large (e.g. more than 1000 records and can be up to 10000 records) then It make my application crashed.

So I am using the code below to fix above problem.

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1))
                    onScrolledToBottom();
            }
        });
```

It can help to reduce the time but the problem changes to be the screen cannot scroll for the whole page.

How can deal with this issue?

> ID: < input box >
>
> ---
>
> item1
>
> item2
>
> item3
>
> item4
>
> item5
>
> item6
>
> ...
>
> item1000

Comment: Are you using RecyclerView for your data or ScrollView (NestedScrollView)? Can you post more info about how you populate your data exactly?

Comment: Making a scrollview with 1000 items or greater is bad practice because your user won't even bother scrolling for that number of items. So create logic/flow that will optimize your list via filtering or user friendly viewing

Comment: Its very common problem in mobile app development & Google has a recommended solution/approach to address it - Its called "Paging" Library - https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging

Comment: You should use _Pagination_ for that

Comment: @Piyush The requirement forced me to shows everything at once :'(

Comment: Then manage it locally!

Comment: @PuifaiiM you dont should use scrollview you should use recyclerview see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44347883/loading-large-number-of-items-in-recycler-view

Answer (score 1):

Pagination is build specifically for this.
You can have a repository which would serve you data .

```
class YourRepository{
    /**
     * Offset would indicate the starting index of data that you need
     * Count indicates the amount of data you need
     **/
    List<Data> getData(int count, int offset){}
}
```

With this api in place, you can use Jetpack Paging library pretty effectively.
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging