# How does my activity run smoothly with lots of High Quality Images in Android?

Tags: android

**Scenario:** Two activites are there in my Android App: Activity X and Activity Y

On Activity X, one button is there, on Clicking of button, I'm opening Activity Y.

Inside OnCreate of Activity Y, I'm calling Firestore Database, and fetching around 10 image link. That image link is dynamic, and also that link is Firebase Storage link, where actual High Quality images are uploaded.

After fetching that images link, I'm setting on ImageView using Glide library.

**Problem:**
Obviously, To show 10 big Image, I added Scrollview in Activity Y XML, so that user can scroll and view the Images. But scrolling behaviour is not smooth. Also this is not just first time problem. After loading all Images into Imageview, after that also If I try to scroll then also scrolling is not smooth.

**Code:**

```
String str = entry.getValue().toString();

switch (entry.getKey()) {
            case "link1":
                setImage(binding.image1, str);
                break;

            case "link2":
                setImage(binding.image2, str);
                break;

            case "link3":
                setImage(binding.image3, str);
                break;

            case "link4":
                setImage(binding.image4, str);
                break;

            case "link5":
                setImage(binding.image5, str);
                break;
        }
    }


     private void setImage(ImageView image1, String str) {
            image1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Glide.with(context).load(str).
                    diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(image1);
        }
```

**UPDATE:**

Tried with Recycyclerview instead of Scrollview, but is it even possible that recycler can be more smooth. I tried with below code.

```
RecyclerView.SmoothScroller smoothScroller = new LinearSmoothScroller(context) {
                    @Override
                    protected int getVerticalSnapPreference() {
                        return LinearSmoothScroller.SNAP_TO_ANY;
                    }
                };
                smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(0);
                mLayoutManager.startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
```

**XML:**

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        tools:listitem="@layout/row_preview_view" />
```

Also, is there any caching mechanism or something possible? I'm using Glide library to load the image. Can I do something with Glide?

Comment: Your update showing your usage of the `RecyclerView` does not look correct. Refer to this guide on how to use the `RecyclerView`: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview. Also, it is not wise to not cache if you do anything regarding the internet. For proper caching, I recommend saving the pictures to files on the device and then store their paths in a `Room` database and load them when needed. `Room`: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room.

Comment: @RenéSpies With Room also it'll be slow because APK MB will be high. No one will download the app

Comment: Everyone will uninstall the app after they see a huge spike in their network data usage because every time they start the app, they download multiple MBs of pictures. For some users this might even produce high costs.

Comment: @RenéSpies Okay as per your suggestion, even If I'll store into SQLite, the APK size will be 76 MB because of around 100 images

Comment: Yes, you cannot magically remove the size of the images. The usual approach for your task would be following.
You store the images online, so the initial size of the APK will not be high because of that.
You let the user decide for each image whether to download it or not, so that the user has control over that.
You download the image and store it on the local drive of the phone and store a reference to this path in your database.
The last step is recommended because storing large objects in the database will cause major performance drawbacks.

Comment: @RenéSpies Everything is fine, but one thing I not understood. As per suggestion, I used Recyclerview, instead of Scrollview. But now first view is setting in middle somewhere and like that. I'm not able to maintain the position.

Comment: That's probably because you have the `height` of the `View` for the `RecyclerView` set to `match_parent`. Instead use `wrap_content`.

Comment: @RenéSpies No dear it's wrap content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe try to replace `Scroll View` with the `Recycler View`. In android docs, we can read *"If your app needs to display a scrolling list of elements based on large data sets (or data that frequently changes), you should use RecyclerView"* [Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview). I am not sure but I think with `Recycler View` it will be more smooth.

Comment: Yes, `RecyclerView` makes major improvements to performance, especially when images are shown. The clue is that `RecyclerView` does not load new elements and images as you scroll down or up but rather recycles the `View` you are scrolling to the top or bottom out of the sight and appends it to the direction you are scrolling.

Comment: Thanks it's working, but I need more smooth. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: @SuchiSingh If You hadn't already done this You can [check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44347883/loading-large-number-of-items-in-recycler-view)

Comment: I not understood this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44429820/13406877

Comment: Everything is fine, but one thing I not understood. As per suggestion, I used Recyclerview, instead of Scrollview. But now first view is setting in middle somewhere and like that. I'm not able to maintain the position.